# MongoDB .Need to count fileds of an array

Tags: mongodb

I have a collection like below

```
{  _id: 1,  zipcode: "63109",  students: [
                   { name: "john", school: 102, age: 10 },
                   { name: "jess", school: 102, age: 11 },
                   { name: "jeff", school: 108, age: 15 }
                ] }



{  _id: 2,  zipcode: "63110",  students: [
                   { name: "ajax", school: 100, age: 7 },
                   { name: "achilles", school: 100, age: 8 },
                ] }

 {  _id: 3,  zipcode: "63109",  students: [
                   {  school: 100, age: 7 },
                   {  school: 100, age: 8 },
                ] }

 {  _id: 4,  zipcode: "63109",  students: [
                   { name: "barney", school: 102, age: 7 },
                   { name: "ruth", school: 102, age: 16 },
                ] }
```

Note:Some document doesnot have **name** field.

I want to findout the count of name field.
Kindly suggest query to find count in mongo

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this with aggregation framework with `$unwind`. Let say your collection name is `test`:

```
db.test.aggregate(
    {$unwind: '$students'}, 
    {$match:{'students.name':{$exists:1}}},
    {$group:{_id: '$students.name', count:{$sum:1}}},
    {$project:{tmp:{name:'$_id', count:'$count'}}}, 
    {$group:{_id:'Total Names', total:{$sum:1}, data:{$addToSet:'$tmp'}}}
)
```

Hope this is what you want!

Answer (score 0):

You need to use the aggregation framework in this case.

The first aggregation step would be to use [$unwind](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/unwind/) to turn the arrays into streams of documents.

Then you can use [$group](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/group/) as a second aggregation step with [`$sum:1`](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/sum/)  to get the count of every name.

```
db.collection.aggregate([    
    { 
        $unwind: "$students" 
    },
    { 
        $group: {
            _id:"$students.name",
            count: { $sum:1 }
        }
    }    
]
```

Comment: Hi Philipp Thanks for your help..I tried my query as per your suggestion.  db.transactions.aggregate([    
    { 
        $unwind: "body.payload.iemRecords" 
    },
    { 
        $group: {
            _id:"$body.payload.iemRecords.CID",
            count: { $sum:1 }
        }
    }    
])  But getting error like  " "exception: field path references must be prefixed with a '$' ('body.payload.iemRecords'","

Comment: @Aman You missed a $-sign in the $unwind. Try `$unwind: "$body.payload.iemRecords"`

Answer (score 0):

This is doable through the aggregation framework

I'll assume your collection is called mycoll:

```
db.mycoll.aggregate([
    {$unwind:'$students'},
    {$group:{_id:'$name', 'count':{$sum:1}},
    {$match:{'students.name':{$exists:1}}}
    ]);
```

References:
Aggregations http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/tutorial/aggregation-zip-code-data-set/
Exists: http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/query/exists/
Summing '1' essentially turns it into a count.